# Store test data on jenkins

Tags: java, testing, jenkins

Can jenkins store custom variables on the server its running on? Essentially what I am doing is passing parameters into a jenkins setup job. These parameters will then be stored in a properties file and used as test data.

For example, I run a job to update a properties file with the current number of active users on the system. I then have tests which access this properties file and confirms the amount of users. Can this be done? Is it bad practice? I know jenkins has a number of environment variables that can be assigned but can it be done with custom variables?

Comment: If you want the data to be persistent/static, put a file in $JENKINS_HOME. Otherwise, put the file in the repository. If it differs from run to run, just recompute it and archive it as a build artifact

Comment: Can you access  $JENKINS_HOME in your code?

Comment: If you run the service as jenkins user, and it is owned/ has right Yes. If you need to access from a slave you will get tangled up in copying files around. I would not advice that solution but it might do the trick